# Define output size of DQN

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I recently learned about Q-Learning with the example of the Gym environment "CartPole-v1".

The predict function of said model always returns a vector that looks like `[[ 0.31341377 -0.03776223]]`. I created my own little game, where the Ai has to move left or right with ouput 0 and 1. I just show a list `[0, 0, 1, 0, 0]` to the network, if it ouputs 0 it goes left, if it outputs 1 it goes right. Reach the left 0 and you win, right 0 and you lose. Really easy. When i print my ouput Vector however, i always get something like this:

```
[[0.01347399 0.04450664]
 [0.01347399 0.04450664]
 [0.01347399 0.04450664]
 [0.1216775  0.38299465]
 [0.01347399 0.04450664]]
```

This messes with the learning function because `np.argmax()` then returns something like  or 5 and the network cannot handle this given the fact that there are only 2 actions to begin with.

This is the init of my model:

```py
    def __init__(self, state_shape, num_actions, lr):
        super(DQN, self).__init__()
        self.state_shape = state_shape # (1,)
        self.num_actions = num_actions # 2
        self.lr = lr # 1e-3

        input_state = Input(shape=state_shape)
        x = Dense(20)(input_state)
        x = Activation('relu')(x)
        x = Dense(20)(x)
        x = Activation('relu')(x)
        output_pred = Dense(self.num_actions)(x)

        self.model = Model(inputs=input_state, outputs=output_pred)
        self.model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer=Adam(lr=self.lr))
```

Full code is available at https://www.mediafire.com/file/rq7ogjxpr990e51/dqn.py/file.

How do i crop the output vector? Or how would i have to change my inputs to get a useful output?

Edit:

I've experimented a little more, and increasing num_actions from currently 2 to for example 4 does increase the vector horizontally, so it looks like this:

```
[[ 0.00109814  0.01464381 -0.00270887 -0.00422738]
 [ 0.00109814  0.01464381 -0.00270887 -0.00422738]
 [-0.01450843  0.10628925 -0.06114068 -0.10908635]
 [ 0.00109814  0.01464381 -0.00270887 -0.00422738]
 [ 0.00109814  0.01464381 -0.00270887 -0.00422738]]
```

This means num_actions as 2 is not the problem, its rather that it ouputs 5 lines instead of 1.

Comment: What do you pass in num_actions?

Comment: In the env it is `[0, 1]`, in the Agent class this gets converted to `len(action_space)` and as in the comment behind self.num_actions, this results in 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after even more experiments, i have found a solution.

The input is still the list `[0, 0, 1, 0, 0]` which has the len() = 5.
This explains the five rows. If its changed to `[[0, 0, 1, 0, 0]]` and the `state_shape` is changed to (5, ) it works and I get a vector with 2 values.

*All the other functions that access the list have to be changed from `board[idx]` to `board[0][idx]`.